# Is it permissible to use "subliminals" in videos to change one's eye color?

Tags: halal-haram, medical, human-body

There are these videos which is like some sort of 'hypnosis' thing for your subconscious mind. It plays these frequencies with an inaudible voice in the background that your subconscious can hear.

Basically, they're used for relaxation, confidence, weight-loss, sleep-even hair growth. It's scientifically proven and I've seen some results posted by regular people, so it works after some weeks.

There are some videos which change your eye color. I've seen some really extreme ones like, brown->green, or blue->violet; but since I'm aware that I shouldn't alter anything on my face for it's altering Allah's creation, I've opted for lighter eyes.

I have dark brown eyes, but the video's purpose is to lighten it to a more 'hazel' color.

I'm not *altering* the eye color, just lightening it. But, I have my doubts, so is it permissible to use this method?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help]

Comment: I think this question would become unnecessary if you took the time to ask people on [health.se](http://health.stackexchange.com) whether this is possible - it's not, but they'll be qualified to explain just how made up the claim is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wa'alikumussalam warahmatullah wa barakatuh: May Allah rewards you with peace, love and blessings.

Any rules in Islam (aka hukum) are based on citation of 2 main source: The Quran and hadith by the prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him).

The basis of Islamic law is that any act is permissible (halal) except those forbidden by Allah and His Rasul.

Satan has declare that they will lead us astray: ([An-Nisaa' 4:118-119](http://www.surah.my/4?l=en#119))

> Allah did curse him (the Satan), but he said: "I will take of Thy
>   servants a portion Marked off; (118)
>   "I will mislead them, and I will create in them false desires; I will order them to slit the ears of cattle, **and to deface the (fair) nature created by Allah.**" Whoever, forsaking Allah, takes satan for a friend, hath of a surety suffered a loss that is manifest. (119)

Set steady to the fitrah created by Allah for us: ([Ar-Ruum 30:30](http://surah.my/30?l=en#30))

> So set thou thy face steadily and truly to the Faith: (establish)
>   Allah.s handiwork according to **the pattern on which He has made**
>   **mankind: no change (let there be) in the work (wrought) by Allah**. that
>   is the standard Religion: but most among mankind understand not.

Narrated 'Abdullah that:

> the Prophet (ﷺ) cursed the women who practice tattooing and those who
>   seek to be tattooed, the women who remove hair from their faces
>   seeking beautification by **changing the creation of Allah**.

We are only allowed to fix injury or disability that we have but we should always appreciate what ever Allah has given to us, how ever it be. Any sign of rejection or dismissal towards Allah's gift for us are strongly a sinful deed.

Reference:
http://www.surah.my/4?l=en#119
http://surah.my/30?l=en#30
http://sunnah.com/search/?q=women+change

Comment: But it's a naturally way, is it really still haram?

Comment: If it is to deface the (fair) nature created by Allah, it is haram. We have to accept the way we are.

Comment: See this video: https://www.facebook.com/kbergetar/videos/1129404430469783/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give also some food of thought to the answer above.  The ayat were clear and I want to ask something else: why do you want to change the color of your eyes?  Is it to be more acceptable or are you not satisfied with the way God created you?

I heard the hadith of the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him): that God does not look into your images nor your bodies but he looks into the taqwa in your hart.

In the [Qur'an chapter infitar verse number 7-8](https://quran.com/82/7), Allah says that He is who created and completed you in any way he wanted to build you, 
so God has chosen your image and color of skin and eyes and how tall you are or how handsome you are and he tells you that the only thing that matter in Allah's judgement is your faith and taqwa, so work on that and don't be bothered if you don't have this color of eyes or this sum of money.

If you want to be truly happy, be satisfied with what Allah gave you 
and put your effort in what you can change like how close you are to Allah and how many good deeds you have done how many people you have helped, and believe if we enter paradise in shaa Allah you can get whatever you pleas and much more, in the jana there are things that you can't imagine and can't even begin to understand in order to imagine and I hope that God will guide us to his path
and astaghfiru Allah if I have mistaken or hurt someone with my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm not a devout muslim myself and I don't wanna mislead anyone by my opinion, however, Islam is all about inquiry and inspecting for yourself in conjunction with Qura'n and sunna, with that being said, why would Allah create biokinesis abilities embedded naturally in human minds and allow us to learn about it if it's really forbidden?? I'm not in a place to say this is haram and this is halal, just food for thought.

Comment: [Biokenesis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biokinesis): "the supposed ability to mentally control the bodily functions of oneself or another".