# Using subliminals for lighter eye color

Tags: practical-islam

Is it haraam to use the youtube 'subliminals' to lighter my eyes? Im not changing it from brown to green or blue...i want to get lighter color eye...is it haraam?am i changing Allah creation cause i just want the color to get lighter
Tq Assalamualaikum

Comment: What are youtube subliminals?

Comment: cant this be covered in http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34947/using-subliminals-to-change-eye-color

Comment: But im not changing it though....is it still haram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam sister,

No, I don't think it's unlawful. What is haram is getting plastic surgery that is not medically necessary. You're not altering the biology of your body, you're just stimulating cells that are already existant.

It's like wearing a nice scarf I would presume. Beauty is not prohibited in Islam, it's encouraged. Just make sure that you're doing it for the right reasons.

Salam